# Стеки на Pascal

Tags: pascal, стек

Решаю задачу про Ханойские башни, если в общем. Написал процедуры для работы со стеками PUSH, POP,SHOW. Сначала они были написаны для одного стека, потом изменил так, чтобы можно было работать с тремя стеками (массивами по сути). После преобразования с процедурой PUSH возникла проблема: получает имя стека(массива) и элемент, который нужно в него положить, но не кладет его в нужное место. я примерно понимаю, в чем проблема, но не знаю как ее решить. И с процедурой POP, думаю, та же проблема будет..
Помогите, кому не сложно

```
var


n,t:integer;
 type ta=array[1..10] of integer; 
 var
 a:ta;
 S1,S2,S3:ta;
 procedure PUSH (a:ta;c:integer);
 begin
 if n<10 then begin {до 10 элементов}
 n:=n+1; {Добавляю элемент}
  a[n]:=с; {и значение}
  end
  else
  writeln ('Переполнение');
 end;
 {функция удаления элемента из стека}
  procedure POP(a:ta);
 begin
  a[n]:=t;
  n:=n-1; {Убираю элемент}
 end;
 {процедура вывода элементов стека на экран}
procedure SHOW; 
 begin
   var i:integer;
   writeln ('S1:');
   for i:=10 downto 1 do
   writeln (S1[i],' ');

   writeln ('S2:');
   for i:=10 downto 1 do
   writeln (S2[i],' ');

   writeln ('S3:');
   for i:=10 downto 1 do
   writeln (S3[i],' ');
   end;
{Основная программа}
begin
 n:=0;
 var i:integer;
 for i:=1 to 10 do 
 begin
  PUSH(S1,(11-i));
 end;
 n:=0;
 for i:=1 to 10 do 
  PUSH(S2,0);
  n:=0;
 for i:=1 to 10 do 
  PUSH(S3,0);

 SHOW;
 end.
```

Comment: Непонятна роль переменной `t`

Answer (score 3):

У вас переменные количества элементов стака (`n`) общие для всех переменных-стеков.

Я почти не знаю Паскаль и используемую вами имплементацию, но рискну предположить, что структуры (в Паскале это зовется `record`) создавать вы можете. Сделайте одну такую из стека как массива и количества элементов в нем, обьявите её как тип и используйте в ваших процедурах. Чтото типа:

```
stek = record
  a: ta; // массив
  count: integer; //число элементов в нем, вместо n
end;
```

Если ваш Pascal объектно-ориентированный (Делфи, Лазарус, Фрипаскаль и т.п.), то вместо структуры создаете класс.

Answer (score 1):

Параметры процедур и функций, которые вы изменяете внутри, должны объявляться как изменяемые - с ключевым словом `var`. Например:

```
procedure PUSH (var a: ta; c: integer);
..
procedure POP (var a: ta);
```

В противном случае вы изменяете локальную (для функции) копию массива и при выходе из неё все изменения теряются.